# Rails soft and hard delete actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud

If I have a model that supports soft deletes (for standard users) and hard-deletes (for admins) what's the best best routing approach?

Does it make sense to handle both request under the same delete action in the controller with logic in the method or does it make sense to have to different routes?

Is a soft delete technically considered a `delete` action?

I know this is overcomplicating it but any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably put a conditional statement within a single action. That way it's transparent to the user and there's no way a user could hack the destroy method by guessing the delete URL and posting to it:

```
# DELETE /thing/1
# DELETE /thing/1.json
def destroy
  @thing = Thing.find(params[:id])

  if current_user.admin? and !params[:soft_delete]
    @thing.destroy
  else
    @thing.soft_delete
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to things_url }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end

# views/things/show.html.erb
<%= button_to("Delete", thing_url(@thing), method: :delete) %>
<%= button_to("Soft Delete", thing_url(@thing, soft_delete: true), method: :delete) %>
```

Comment: I like this but what if an admin needs the option to do a soft and hard delete?

Comment: You could `if current_user.admin? and !params[:soft_delete]`. Then in your view you could have a button like `<%= button_to("Soft Delete", thing_url(@thing, soft_delete: true), method: :delete) %>` which would pass the `soft_delete` param.

Answer (score 0):

Unless an admin may need to perform a soft delete, using the same route for both actions decreases the number of routes to handle.

Using a DELETE action for both operations is OK. From the client point of view it's just deleting something (no need to know if it's soft or hard).